# Swift Variable Name

Tags: swift, variables

Is it possible to find out the variable name, what I called it, while the variable has a value?

**SO what I mean is:**

```
var varName: Int
...
if ((varName == "varName") && (varName == 6)) {
...
}
```

---

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look about `Reflection` in `Swift` example below

```
struct Car  {

let type: CarType
let name: String

init(_ type: CarType, name: String) {
    self.type = type
    self.name = name
}
}

enum CarType {
    case Sport
    case Economics
}

let bmw = Car(CarType.Sport, name: "BMW")

let bmwMirror = Mirror(reflecting: bmw)

let children = bmwMirror.children

print("car properties: \(children.count)") //2

var generator = children.generate()
let type = generator.next()
print(type!.label) // type Optional
print(type!.value) //Sport
let name = generator.next()
print(name!.label) // name Optional
print(name!.value) //BMW
```

Note : I am using Swift 2.0 Xcode beta 7 in Swift 1.2 use `let bmwMirror = reflect(bmw)`
and you can access the properties `bmwMirror.[indexOfProperty].1(.value or label)`

Comment: Sometimes its better to not answer OP's original question, because his/her design pattern is clearly wrong, you should never in real code compare a string with a variable name, that's just bad.

Comment: I'm using swift 1.2. So there isn't a way to make the code shorter. Or I can just use an `array` and store the name I want in the first index and the value in the second index.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to check variable name? Maybe better to use dictionary instead?

If you make variable names from string and then check it for right names, maybe better to check original strings?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @TAsk You're right in that it doesn't provide an answer, but it guides OP in the right direction, comparing Strings with variable names is a horrible anti-pattern.

Comment: @TAsk as you can see I have no enough reputation for comment post except mine. I have just suggested another solution, because problem is not clear.