# dynamic setting and getting values from Swift class

Tags: swift, core-data

I'd like to copy all properties from a NSManagedObject over to a "regular" Swift class. I don't want to do this manually, i.e. make a regular class with all the properties for every NSManagedObject and then manually copy all those values.

I do know how to read property names and values dynamically from my managed object, but how to set them on a Swift class in a way that I can then use those values like

```
mySwiftObject.name
```

which returns a String or

```
mySwiftObject.age
```

which returns a Number (as those are the types on the Managed Object). Custom subscripting and stuff like that came to my mind, but I didn't manage to achieve this... Is there a nice way to do exactly that?

Comment: You'll have to define all the properties in your "regular" Swift class, I don't think there is a way around that. If the properties have the same name and type as the NSManagedObject properties (and the Swift class inherits from NSObject) then you can use Key-Value coding to copy a set of properties between them, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422180/core-data-setvalue-for-multiple-attributes-at-once for an example.

Comment: I dont know if this heelp but try to look at it *Reflection in Swift* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351984/swift-variable-name/32353067#32353067

Comment: @Bobj-C Reflection is read-only in Swift, so the native Swift class wouldn't be writable

Comment: What do you want to copy these values **to**? Properties of the target object? Something else?